# xcode 5 deprecation warning about glut functions

Tags: opengl, glut, xcode5, deprecated, osx-mavericks

I just upgrade my mac os x 10.6.8 to 10.9 this morning. Everything goes fine except the Xcode 5 with OpenGL Glut APIs. Whenever I run my program involving glut functions, I got 30 deprecation warns, like:

```
'gluErrorString' is deprecated: first deprecated in OS X 10.9.
'glutBitmapCharacter' is deprecated: first deprecated in OS X 10.9.
'glutSwapBuffers' is deprecated: first deprecated in OS X 10.9.
'glutDisplayFunc' is deprecated: first deprecated in OS X 10.9.
'glutIdelFunc' is deprecated: first deprecated in OS X 10.9.
...
```

Comment: `gluErrorString()` isn't a GLUT function.

Comment: The warnings appear to be showing up for all GLUT and GLU functions.  I am also seeing warnings on gluPerspective for example.

Answer (score 11):

Change "OS X Deployment Target" back to OSX10.8, then it works. Hope they will deal with it soon.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! But I still have no idea about the reason. A bug or a recommendation to use some sophisticated way to utilize OpenGL APIs? There must exist distinct features under the 10.9 architecture.

Comment: They're deprecated functions, but the documentation doesn't say which functions to use instead.

Comment: How do you change it back? Because I have this in my CMakeList.txt: if( APPLE  )
 set(CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES "x86_64")
 if(CMAKE_GENERATOR STREQUAL Xcode)
  set(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET "10.8")
 endif()
endif()

And it still gives me those warnings..

Answer (score 9):

I encountered a similar problem with OSX Mavericks.

If the messages are annoying, add compile options to:

```
-Wno-deprecated
```

Comment: This option I have used before, however, this may hide some information I should know. But still thanks for you reply!

Comment: Yes, hiding all warnings is of course not a good way. How about trying other libraries? (eg.GLFW)

Comment: @akihiko : GLFW is a alternative to GLUT, but since Mavericks they also deprecate GLU functions, and I haven't found a replacement provided.

Comment: alternatively, try `-Wno-deprecated-declarations` instead