# Open GL and GLUT is deprecated in 10.9

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, glut

I recently found out how to create a window in xcode c++, but when i tried to use glutInit it said that it was "deprecated in 10.9" so now i would like to know if there is an alternative to glutInit and other glut stuff

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568088/xcode-5-deprecation-warning-about-glut-functions

Comment: cool thanks, will this not allow me to then run my app on 10.9 or will it just run as if it were 1.8?

Comment: It will let you run it just fine. It is a warning not an error. But the general idea is to get you to stop using that framework. The same thing will happen if you try to use AGL (Apple's low-level C based interface for managing GL contexts that are capable of drawing into a window) on 10.9. You can still do it, but you will have no way of creating a core profile context.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to GLUT, GLFW does almost as much as what GLUT can do, as GLUT does have a few commands that uses the fixed pipeline.