# 'gluErrorString' is deprecated in OS X 10.9. Why?

Tags: macos, opengl, deprecation-warning

I am referring to errors of the following form when compiling on OSX:

```
'gluErrorString' is deprecated: first deprecated in OS X 10.9
```

A cursory google+DDG indicates that a bunch of GLU and GLUT functions were deprecated as well, but [Apple's reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/releasenotes/General/APIDiffsMacOSX10_9/OpenGL.html) has no information regarding the reasoning behind the change or the suggested successor(s). I'm not using GLUT and simply want to get a human-readable error description from GL.

Existing answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568088/xcode-5-deprecation-warning-about-glut-functions) and others suggest using a different framework, targeting earlier OSX versions, or suppressing the warnings, but I cannot find evidence of a proper solution.

So, what happened? And what's the recommended way to get an error string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The GLU specification has not been updated since 1998. Large parts of its functionality depend on OpenGL features that have long been deprecated. If you look at the man pages on opengl.org, the latest GLU documentation is grouped with the [OpenGL 2.1 man pages](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/).

Based on this, it certainly makes sense to consider GLU deprecated for OpenGL versions past 2.1.

As for `gluErrorString()`, there are only 6 possible error codes returned by `glGetError()`. Generating a string for each of them only takes a few lines of code.